# How to combine 12-hour time sheet and AM/PM column from spreadsheet in r

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a spreadsheet that has the date and 12 hour time in one column and then another column that specifies AM/PM. How do I combine these files so I can use them as a POSIXct/POSIXlt/POSIXt object?

The spreadsheet has the time column as
DAY/MONTH/YEAR HOUR:MINUTE

while hour is in a 12-hour format from a roster of check in times. The other column just says AM or PM. I am trying to combine these columns and then convert them to 24 hour time and use it as a POSIXt object.

Example of what I see:

| Timesheet | AM-PM |
| --- | --- |
| 8/10/2022 9:00 | AM |
| 8/10/2022 9:01 | AM |

And this continues until 5:00 PM (same day)

What I have tried so far:

```
Timesheet %>%
  unite("timestamp_24", c("timestamp_12","am_pm"),na.rm=FALSE)%>%
  mutate(timestamp=(as.POSIXct(timestamp, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"))
```

This does not work as when they are combined it gives:
Timestamp_24
DAY/MONTH/YEAR HOUR:MINUTE_AM
and I think this is the crux of the issue because then `as.POSIXct` can't read it.

Comment: Sample data please? We know nothing of the _real_ content of `Timesheet` (often how it appears it not how it is stored underneath, and that can make a difference). Please add sample data, perhaps `dput(head(Timesheet))`.

Comment: @r2evans I added an example from the timesheet

Comment: What's the *actual* file format? CSV? Excel? Date columns in Excel have no format. They're binary date values (stored as OLE Automation Dates) even if the cell's numeric style specifies a 12 or 24 hour display form. Either `Timesheet` is a text field, or the actual time is AM in both cases. Unless a custom style is used to display 12-hour without the AM/PM indicator

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the initial question. The data is in csv format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. The approach is simply to extract the hour, +12 if it is PM, then format correctly with as.POSXct (you need to use `/` rather than `-` in the `format` argument if the your dataframe is at is appears in your example).
I've done that with `stringr::str_replace()` which allows you to set a function for the `replace` argument.

```
Timesheet %>% 
  mutate(
    time_24hr = stringr::str_replace(
      time, 
      "\\d+(?=:..$)",
      function(x) {
        hr <- as.numeric(x) %% 12
        ifelse(am_pm == "PM", hr + 12, hr)
      }
    ),
    time_24hr = as.POSIXct(time_24hr, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
  )
```

This is the result:

```
             time am_pm           time_24hr
1  8/10/2022 9:00    AM 2022-10-08 09:00:00
2  8/10/2022 9:01    PM 2022-10-08 21:01:00
3 8/10/2022 12:01    PM 2022-10-08 12:01:00
4 8/10/2022 12:01    AM 2022-10-08 00:01:00
```

EDIT. realized that this didn't work for 11 and 12 as the regex was only extracting the first character before `:`. Also wasn't working for 12:xx times. Fixed both. Added test cases to show that these work now.

Comment: This is assuming the times are just held in the dataframe as strings, but you could alter this approach easily if it isn't by converting to a string first.

Comment: When I do this, it doesn't add 12 hours successfully. Everything else works, however I still can't get it to move to a 24-hour clock. When I run this for example it says 1:00 PM is:
2022-10-08 01:00:00
When it should be 2022-10-08 13:00:00 correct? Could this be the string you mentioned? How would I convert to string first?

Comment: Correction, this works I converted to string. However there is an error with 12:00PM because it adds 12 to that and the result is NA (24:01 isnt a thing). How do I tell it in the function to only add 12 if it is PM AND the number is less than 12?

Comment: Thanks Cole, I realized there were two bugs in the previous code (see my EDIT message on the answer), now I've fixed both, so should work now!